# cognitive serices OCR Pros and cons

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying out the ocr service. Some text it recognises better than "normal" (logos with an unusual font) , some text not recognised at all (some in areas where there's a non-white background).
Is there anything I can do to improve the recognition?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to preprocess the image then apply OCR, you can try OpenCV to enhance the image then send it to the OCR service. (There is no documentation for preprocessing  or any other parameter.)

If you want a more personalized algorithm Opencv + Tesseract are the definitive option.